# Alarms are not working, after same version of app was re-installed

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So I got this in my application's manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".alarms.AlarmReScheduler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <!--For HTC devices-->
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I used **AlarmRescheduler** to re-schedule alarms after the android device re-boots. It works. But when I re-install **same** or **another** version of my app, **AlarmRescheduler** doesn't isn't triggered.

I used this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
```

because, I want it that, after re-install, **AlarmRescheduler** is called again to re-schedule alarms, because after re-install alarms don't seem to work anymore. Was I wrong using `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />` ?

Comment: `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />` is only sent when your app is the upgrade version, same version wont work

Comment: @PhúcNguyễn so what should I use if the user tries to re-install the same version? I know this doesn't make sense, but it can happen. When I re-install through Android Studio, alarms stop working.

Comment: I dont know how to deal with the situation in AS, but for debugging, your app should have some way to store that information to be re-scheduled. In real world, I think user have to start over again, there is no way